# In C, append to file open for read by another program on Windows console and Linux

Tags: c, linux, file-io

I have two different C programs running on the same machine.  The first program, called FileReader, opens a file for reading, and keeps it open.  Periodically, I want another program, FileAppender, to open the file using the "a" (append) mode, append data, and then close the file.

But I don't want FileReader to close the file whenever the FileAppender needs to append data.

My questions: First, can this be done at all, and if so, can it be done in a portable, reliable way for both Windows console program and Linux? The reason I'm asking about "reliable" is because I am afraid that in testing it may work, but not necessarily reliably.

Second, if this can be done, portability- and reliability-wise, how can the FileReader program know if data has been appended?  One thought I had was to do an fseek to EOF, but worry about the situation where FileAppender is still in the process of writing data to the file.

Comment: Your situation sounds much like a `pipe`. Would it really be a problem for the reader to block if the writer isn't done? Would your reader have something better to do?

Comment: @EOF, I'm a newbie, so not sure about how pipes work.  But it would certainly be fine if this were to happen: FileReader can check somehow that data is being appended, and wait until the append operation is finished.  Is there a portable way to do this?  How would FileReader determine if FileAppender is active?

Comment: The traditional `pipe`-way of life: The producer (write-end of the pipe) does whatever it does, writes its results to the pipe, and blocks when the pipe is full. The consumer (read-end) blocks in a read of the pipe until data is available, is automagically woken by the OS once data has been written, consumes that data. Since the pipe is no longer full, the producer is awoken, and everyone is happy.

Comment: Regarding _But I don't want FileReader to close the file whenever the FileAppender needs to append data_.  Does this mean you want FileAPpender to wait until file is closed, then open and append?

Comment: The `tail` command acts like a *FileReader*, and does the job without any cooperation from the *FileAppender*. (Use `tail -f filename` to run in *FileReader* mode.) Be sure that the *FileAppender* calls `fflush` whenever it wants the *FileReader* to see changes. Otherwise, the system may buffer the data until `fclose` is called.  So my suggestion is to rummage around the internet to find the source code for `tail` to see how they did it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Linux/UNIX -tail command as described in the comments does not exist for windows, But yes, there are several ways to do this even without that command.  Here is one that I have used, that should work cross-platform:

First recognize you are describing a ***shared*** (file system) ***resource***, that can only be accessed by one process at any one time. The two (or more) applications need some kind of semaphore (signalling) method  to signal the current state of the target file by checking the existence of another.  I have used a *Token* file for this, and it has worked for me.  A *Token* file is simply a file with a unique name that indicates *permission* to access the target file, ***where target file is*** the file being edited by more than one process.   This Token file can be checked by processes (applications) for its existence.   If token exists, the target file is busy, and should not be accessed.  If the token does not exist, create it, then access the target file.  Close token when done appending to target.

Simple concept flow:

```
Process 1
while(token exists)
{
   //Sleep(20)
}
create token
Open target file for append
write to target file
close target file
close token

Process 2
while(token exists)
{
   //Sleep(20)
}
create token
Open target file for append
write to target file
close target file
close token
```